# Declare custom value for boolean true of false

Tags: javascript

I vaguely remember that I've seen custom values for a boolean true/false sometimes, but I have no idea what it is called or how exactly it was written.

So I have this code:

```
 preferenceHotel = document.getElementById('preference-hotel').checked;
```

Now instead of `preferenceHotel` returning true or false, I would like it to return other values (yes or no), without writing an if statement checking whether it is true or false.

I remember something like this:

```
 preferenceHotel = document.getElementById('preference-hotel').checked:"yes"|"no";
```

Does anybody know what I mean and know the name of it so I can read the documentation? (+ write it for my use case).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [ternary operator](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/) ? like `preferenceHotel = document.getElementById('preference-hotel').checked ? 'yes' : 'no';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using Ternary operators in JavaScript

```
let preferenceHotel = (document.getElementById('preference-hotel').checked) ? "yes" : "no";
```

[Conditional Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
preferenceHotel = document.getElementById('preference-hotel').checked ? "yes" : "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  preferenceHotel = document.getElementById('preference-hotel').checked?"yes": "no";
```

Comment: please add some explanation on what that code does.